# Select distinct totals from access tables

Tags: ms-access

I have three tables: T_O, T_C, & T_D they each have a date (run_date) and count column.
I need to select the data to show a summary by date for each count. I cannot get the nested sql to make it look right.

Needs to be grouped by Run Date.  End result should look like this:

```
Run_Date    Total Defects   Not Closed    Closed
05/29/13    178             100           78
06/04/13    204             103           101
06/11/13    234             114           120
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the three tables each have two columns: `Run_Date` and `Total Defects`, `Not Closed` or `Closed`. If you have a table with all the run dates in it, something like this will work:

```
SELECT
  RunDates.Run_Date,
  T_D.[Total Defects],
  T_O.[Not Closed],
  T_C.[Closed]

FROM ((
  RunDates
  LEFT JOIN T_C ON RunDates.Run_Date = T_C.Run_Date)
  LEFT JOIN T_O ON RunDates.Run_Date = T_O.Run_Date)
  LEFT JOIN T_D ON RunDates.Run_Date = T_D.Run_Date
```

If not, you will need to construct one using a UNION (not UNION ALL):

```
SELECT
  RunDates.Run_Date,
  T_D.[Total Defects],
  T_O.[Not Closed],
  T_C.[Closed]

FROM ((
  (SELECT Run_Date FROM T_C
   UNION
   SELECT Run_Date FROM T_O
   UNION SELECT Run_Date FROM T_D) AS RunDates
   LEFT JOIN T_C ON RunDates.Run_Date = T_C.Run_Date)
   LEFT JOIN T_O ON RunDates.Run_Date = T_O.Run_Date)
   LEFT JOIN T_D ON RunDates.Run_Date = T_D.Run_Date
```